# Component that takes displays form data returns a warning. The warning is [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

The component I am trying to get to display information is this one. It is called Addedinfo

```
    <template>
  <section class = "container">
    <h1> My info </h1>
      <ul>
        <li v-for "info in information" :key="info.id"> {{ info.text }} </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ["information"],
  };
</script>
```

Addedinfo is nested in a component called Belay, which is here

```
    <template>
  <div style = "text-align: left;">
    <h1>Enter Info</h1>
    <added-info :information="filteredInfos"></added-info>
    <add-information @add-info="another"> </add-information>
  </div>
</template>



<script>
  import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
  import AddInformation from "../components/AddInformation.vue";
  import AddedInfo from "../components/AddedInfo.vue";

  export default{
    components: {
      AddInformation,
      AddedInfo,

    },

    setup() {
      const infos = ref([]);

      const filteredInfos = computed(function() {
        return infos.value.filter(
          (info) => !info.text.includes("Angular") && !info.text.includes("React")
        );
      });

      function another(text) {
        const newVar = {
          id: new Date().toISOString(),
          text: text,
        };
        infos.value.push(newVar);
      }

      return {
        filteredInfos: filteredInfos,
        another: another
      };

    }
  };

</script>
```

The component Addinfo (not included) takes information and the component Addedinfo is supposed to display it on Belay. Instead, upon entering information and submitting. I receive the following error-

```
[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
  at <AddedInfo information= [] > 
  at <Belay onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AddInfo component template

```
<ul>
    <li v-for "info in information" :key="info.id"> {{ info.text }} </li>
</ul>
```

v-for is missing the '=' sign.  Should be:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="info in information" :key="info.id"> {{ info.text }} </li>
</ul>
```